# Remove folder but not the files within it

Tags: git, directory, subdirectory

How can I remove a folder but keep the files within it with Git?

For example, let’s say I have a folder called ‘MyFolder’ under my repository folder (RepoFolder/MyFolder) and inside ‘MyFolder’ I have files ‘file1’ and ‘file2’ (RepoFolder/MyFolder/file1 file2)

I just want to remove the ‘MyFolder’ folder and keep files ‘file1’ and ‘file2’ under ‘RepoFolder’

Comment: git mv MyFolder/* ./; rm -rf MyFolder

Comment: One update to @avejidah `git mv MyFolder/* .` then `git rm -rf MyFolder`

Comment: You don't need to remove the directory from Git, because Git doesn't track directories in the first place. (You would want to remove the empty directory from your working directory, though.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! As @chepner mentioned, I didn't have to remove MyFolder, it automatically disappeared from my repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have what's probably the answer you want:

```
git mv MyFolder/* .
```

followed by removal of the now-empty folder.

Be aware, however, that you are, in part, manipulating files and folders in your *work-tree*.  Git does not store what's in your work-tree; rather, Git stores what you have told Git to copy to Git's *index*.

This is what running `git add` all the time is about: every `git add` you run tells Git: *copy this to the index*.  You can't work directly on files that are in the index: they're in a special Git-only form.  You need copies that you *can* work with.  Git puts those in your work-tree.  But Git makes *new* commits from the index, not from your work-tree.

Files in the index—and in Git—aren't *in* folders.  They just have long names with slashes.  That is, in the index, you currently have `MyFolder/file1`—that's a *file*, there's no folder, it's just a file named `MyFolder/file1`—and `MyFolder/file2`.  If you make a commit now, the *commit* will have those files, with those long names, as well.

If and when you tell Git to extract some commit, and *in* that commit, there is a file named `super/calli/fragial/istic/expi/ali/docious`, Git may have to tell your *computer* to make folders `super` (in `.`), `calli` (in `super`), and so on, so as to put in a file named `docious`.  Git understands that your computer demands that files go into folders, rather than just having long names.  Git will *make* these folders as needed.  But Git never *stored* the folders!  It just stored a file with the long name.

In any case, if you use `git mv MyFolder/file1 file1` to rename `MyFolder/file` to `file1`, so that your *computer* moves the file out of the folder, Git now has the name `file1` in Git's index, and you have the file named `file1` in your work-tree.  Repeat for `file2` and now presumably `MyFolder` is empty.  If Git has, in Git's index, no files whose name starts with `MyFolder/`, Git won't *make* directory `MyFolder` in your work-tree any more.  But Git won't *remove* it either: you must do that yourself.

(Since Git's index *does* have files named `file1` and `file2` in it, the *next* commit you make will contain files by that name.  The *current* commit continues to have `MyFolder/file1` and `MyFolder/file2` in it.  If, in the future, you go back and extract this commit into your work-tree, Git will create `MyFolder/` if it has to.)